# IPad3 iOs7 localStorage quotaExceededError

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, ios7

Im having this weird problem, google is no help. Getting the *QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22* on iPad3, iOs7 7.0.4, Safari 9537.53 (version 7, WebKit 537.51.1). Just to cut out all the answers from the internet, my private browsing is **OFF**. Settings change did not help. Cleaning out all the browser data didn't help as well. Soo, any advice? localStorage aint working on any website.

Answer (score 0):

You might have disabled the Cookies. This is a bug on iOS7 that if you have disabled the Cookies, localStorage will not work and gives this error.
Try enabling cookies, then it should work.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I've reset all Safari settings to default.